# Oscilloscope not visible in PROTEUS simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, simulation, electrical, proteus

I tried simulating astable multivibrator using OPAMP. At one instant i got the oscilloscope but wasn't able view the waveform. I tried running again but this time there was no oscilloscope visible. Can anyone tell me the problem. If not, can you suggest me a better simulator to simulate analog circuits . Most of them include OPAMP and some logic gates, comparators. I want to view the analog output waveforms in most of the cases.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens after you have clicked the 'x' on the oscilloscope to close it, so when you next run the simulation it isn't there.

If you go to the top menu and find the 'Debug' option, at the bottom will be a list of debugging tools you are using. The Digital Oscilloscope should be there at the bottom. Click that and it'll reappear.